For loop is not continuing till number becomes 0
I have a java program which count the digits in the integer using for loop
it returns me the count as count of digit minus 1
For eg.
if i enter 6 digit integer it returns count of 5

if I enter 10 digit integer it returns count of 9

public class DigitCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a=123456;
        int count=0;

        for (int i=0;i<=a;i++){
            a=a/10;
            count++;


        }

        System.out.println(" numb of digits are :  "+ count);
    }
}



... Initialize count to 1 instead of 0 then?

by the way, almost all answer fail for input 0 (unless that is considered to be no digit at all) but easy to correct ( if (a == 0) count = 1; )

in your case, it is better to use 'while' instead of 'for' since you don't know how many iterations you need.
like:
public class DigitCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a=123456;
        int count=0;

        while (a>0){
            a=a/10;
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(" numb of digits are :  "+ count);
    }
}


fails for 0|| and we could use while (a != 0) so  it also works for negative numbers (but also fails for zero)

Use Math
The logarithm is the relationship between a number and the number of digits that number has1. So we can "count" the digits by taking the logarithm of the value in question.
int a = 1234567890;
int count = 1 + (int) (Math.log(a) / Math.log(10));
System.out.printf("Number of digits in %d is %d%n", a, count);

Alternatively
With your for loop approach, instead of modifying2 a while you loop, you could start i at 1 and multiply by 10 on each iteration. Like,
for (long i = 1; i <= a; i *= 10) {
    count++;
}

Which should fix your issue.
1Proof: How many digits does a number have? ⌊log10⌋+1

2Because Computers Suck at Division

in second approach - it is better to change int i to long i, so it will not overflow for numbers around 2^31

@IłyaBursov Fair and thank you.

The best way for the requirement using the input number/10 is a while loop.
Anyway, as you wanted to use the for loop to implement this, try this solution.
public class DigitCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 123456;

        int count = 0;

        for (; a != 0; a /= 10, count++){
            // No need for a separate line to increment the count.
        }

        System.out.println("Number of digits is:  "+ count);
    }
}


How does a = Math.abs(num); prevent anything? 1) the loop will work the same with negative numbers; 2) a is never used

I'm not really sure what you're looking for, but the main problem with your current code is invalid loop termination condition, you need to check a, not i
for (int i=0; a!=0; i++) {
    a = a/10;
    count++;
}

note: variable i in this loop is actually count of digits, so instead of declaring useless variable - you can just use count, like:
int count;
for (count = 0; a!=0; count++) {
    a = a/10;
}


Here's how you can fix your program to correctly count the number of digits:
public class DigitCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 123456;
        int count = 0;
        int originalNumber = a;

        for (; a != 0; a = a / 10) {
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println("Number of digits in " + originalNumber + " are: " + count);
    }
}


I want to use for loop

updated the code.

No please, wanted conventional for loop

A "conventional" for loop needs something to iterate over. What would that be?
